# Hot reloading not working in React Native using Docker

Tags: docker, react-native, docker-compose, expo, hot-reload

I'm trying to get started with React Native on my Windows 10 machine using Docker containers. I get an app running, I connect to it via LAN, but when I change the code, it doesn't change on my device, even if I shake and press Reload.

I'm using the Expo client on my Android phone to open the app. The app is the basic multiple page template offered by `expo init`. As it suggests, I edited `screens/HomeScreen.js`, but the app didn't change. I have Live Reloading and Hot Reloading enabled. Pressing Reload reloads the app, but it stays the same. When I `cat` the file inside the container, it is changed, it just so happens that the bundler doesn not pick up the changes.

I have the following folder structure:

```
.
├── dev
│   ├── MyProject1
│   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  app:
    build: ./dev
    volumes:
      - ./dev:/code
    environment:
      - REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.19
    working_dir: /code/MyProject1
    command: expo start
    ports:
      - "19000:19000"
      - "19001:19001"
      - "19002:19002"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.5.0-alpine

RUN apk add bash

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN npm install -g expo-cli
```

The MyProject1 folder contains the app itself.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but maybe it helps someone.

I had the same issue and solved it by using 'chokidar' https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar
.

After installing chokidar you would have to change this in your docker-compose.yml file:
`command: CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true expo start`

**Note:** I tried this on a Windows 10 machine but it didn't live reload. However, doing this on a Ubuntu machine worked as intended.